# Automatically Save Query Results to Excel

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, jobs, sql-server-agent

I have a simple query that I want to run and save the results in excel file on daily basis.
I am trying to create a SSIS(SQL Server Integration Services) package to automate this thing.
My query is

```
select * from Customers c , Orders o where c.Company =  'Company A'
```

I was able to create a package and run it using Integration Service, but the issue is that when I make changes in the database and re run the package, instead of overwriting the existing excel, it simply appends the new rows. Is there any way that I can overwrite the existing excel?

The second issue is, I can't see the option to schedule the package under integration services. When I right-click on the package name, I see the following

[image]

There is no option to schedule the package.

Is there another way, I can achieve the same purpose? I tried creating a job also -
[image]

I choose the target file as an excel file which was already not present in the system -
[image]

After the job executes successfully, it creates the excel but I can't open it, it says the file is corrupted.

EDIT : My SSISDB doesn't show any packages. When I created the package, it showed me two options, either store it on sql server or file system, so I chose file system -

[image: ![enter image description here]

Steps how I created the package -

I right clicked the database -> Export Data -> specified the data source-> specified the above query-> saved the ssis on file system .
Initially, my package was not automatically present under the file system.I had to import it manually.
I followed the steps from here -

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/202/simple-way-to-export-data-from-sql-server/

Comment: You schedule jobs, in SQL Server, in SQL Server Agent, not SSIS. Also, why are you not using the SSISDB deployment method?

Comment: @Larnu I tried both. In SSISDB, as I have mentioned in my screenshot above, I can't find the option to schedule after I right click the package and then it is appending the excel not overwriting it

Comment: None of those screenshots are of SSISDB. If you are referencing [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlILt.png) that package is deployed by the **file system** deployment method.

Comment: Separate note, as well, it's **2022**, there is no reason to have no adopted the ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax by now; it's been around for *30 years*. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @Larnu This query was only written as a test purpose. Let me post the SSISDB screenshot also

Comment: As for the Output file that outputs a text file, not an Excel document. This is why Excel is telling you that the data is corrupted; it isn't a valid xlsx file.

Comment: @Larnu, so how do I write it as a excel?

Comment: You should be using your SSIS package to do that,

Comment: @Larnu yes, that is working but I am facing two issues in that, the excel appending data and not finding an option to schedule for daily

Comment: Again, you schedule jobs, in SQL Server, in SQL Server Agent not SSIS. YOu can't right click a package in the SSISDB/FileSystem and say "run this once a day" you need to create an Agent Job that uses an SSIS step to run the package with the schedule you need.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry I am trying this for the first time, but I have scheduled the package under integration services. When I faced issues with excel then I tried with jobs

Comment: So if you've scheduled it, what is the problem..?

Comment: Instead of overwriting the existing excel, it simply appends the new rows. And there is no option to schedule the package(screenshot), It is under the integration services header. How to schedule it for daily basis?

Comment: Then the problem is your SSIS package, you need to change that so that it isn't appending. That has *nothing* to do with SQL Server Agent.

Comment: okay let me post steps how I created it.

Comment: *"My SSISDB doesn't show any packages."* That's a picture of the database, not the [catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdodH.png).

Comment: @Larnu replaced the image with that of catalog